# Beginner programmer using eclipse. Error: Could not find or load main class.

Tags: eclipse

I have read the other posts asking the same question but was unable to get my code to work. I have deleted my meta data and imported my files back in to no avail.

I have my workspace inside my dropbox folder to allow me to code from home or while away. Currently I am using my laptop which is not my primary coding machine. The project worked yesterday on this laptop however.

any help would be much obliged, I will provide any information that is required

Comment: Do you have a "main" method in one of your classes?  With what type of project are you working?  Plain java?  other?

Answer (score 0):

First go to the Project menu and select "Clean...".  That might solve it right off the bat.

If not, next you should right click on your "src" folder and select "Build Path" -> "Use as Source Folder".  Then Clean again.

Try those two things and then report back with results.

Comment: I was able to get the code to work. I tried both these without success so I made a new project and copied and pasted all my code over. Now it works.